# ADF Mapping Data Flows - Reuse single running spark cluster for parallel execution of mapping data flows

Tags: azure, apache-spark, azure-data-factory

We have a complex ETL in ADF running multiple pipelines with data flow activities to load several tables in a data-warehouse based on table dependencies.

As a result of running multiple pipelines with inter-dependencies, several data flows are executed as a mix of some running sequentially and some running in parallel. It looks like each data flow running in parallel spins up a new spark cluster, which is causing our daily ETL run cost to skyrise!

Ideally we would like the spark cluster to be reused for all parallel data flow execution, if possible. Is there a way to specify an upper limit for the number of spark clusters that should be created for parallel data flow execution?

We already have TTL enabled for 10 mins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have TTL enabled, make sure to execute data flows using that Azure IR in sequence so that you don't spin-up multiple cluster pools.

To execute in parallel, use Azure IR without TTL.

We are working on the "max concurrency" feature you mention above, hope to land that soon.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up about the "max concurrency" feature. Is there a timeline when we can expect that?  (I will hold off complete refactoring our ETL if this is coming out in next few months)